# Oscillates and Diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How is it possible for sequences to both oscillate and diverge as oscillating sequences are known to neither diverge or converge? For example $\{(-n)^n\}$ has oscillates and diverges, but it does not make sense to me.

Comment: "Diverges" usually means "does not converge."

Answer (score 1):

For a series to diverge, it should simply "not converge". It can show any behaviour it wants while not converging - either growing asymptotically, or oscillating. Both are valid

A series is said to oscillate if it's partial sums, well, oscillate - that is, some terms are less than another and others are larger as we go along the terms.

One does not exclude the other.

For example, $x \sin x$ is a function that is both oscillatory and diverging (I'm playing fast and loose with terminimology here)

However, $\sin x e^{-x}$ is oscillatory and convergent

- [Link to desmos to play with $x \sin x$, $e^{-x} \sin x$](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/uxyaswilfi)